# Issue with jssor slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jssor

I used a banner slider in my site from this link

www.jssor.com/demos/banner-slider.html

I use second one ,but when I zoom in the page in my browser the slider can't cover all width of page and its appearance become not good at all

- I but this slider in container but without benefit , and I try to resize the image on it but this not good solution because it show to me scroll in bottom

How can it fit in my page?

The code for slider as following:

```
<!--  start script jassor slidetr -->
     <!-- it works the same with all jquery version from 1.x to 2.x -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- use jssor.slider.mini.js (40KB) instead for release -->
    <!-- jssor.slider.mini.js = (jssor.js + jssor.slider.js) -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>

 <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-slideshow-no-jquery.html
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html

            var _SlideshowTransitions = [
            //Fade Fly in R
            {$Duration: 1200, x: -0.3, $During: { $Left: [0.3, 0.7] }, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Outside: true }
            //Fade Fly out L
            , { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.3, $SlideOut: true, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2, $Outside: true }
            ];

            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-caption-no-jquery.html
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/reference-ui-definition.html#captiondefinition
            //Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/tool-caption-transition-viewer.html

            var _CaptionTransitions = [];
            _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 800, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 800, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 800, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 800, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["TL"] = { $Duration: 800, x: 0.6, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["TR"] = { $Duration: 800, x: -0.6, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["BL"] = { $Duration: 800, x: 0.6, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["BR"] = { $Duration: 800, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };

            _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR"] = { $Duration: 600, $Clip: 3, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic };
            _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|L"] = { $Duration: 600, $Clip: 1, $Move: true, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic };
            _CaptionTransitions["LISTH|L"] = { $Duration: 1000, x: 0.8, $Clip: 1, $Easing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic, $ScaleClip: 0.8, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0.4, 0.6], $Clip: [0, 0.4], $Opacity: [0.4, 0.6]} };
            _CaptionTransitions["WAVE|L"] = { $Duration: 1300, x: 0.6, y: 0.3, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Top: 2.5} };
            _CaptionTransitions["JUMPDN|R"] = { $Duration: 1000, x: -0.6, y: 0.4, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutJump }, $Round: { $Top: 1.5} };
            _CaptionTransitions["DDG|TR"] = { $Duration: 1200, x: -0.3, y: 0.3, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.8], $Top: [0, 0.8] }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 0.8} };
            _CaptionTransitions["DODGEDANCE|L"] = { $Duration: 1200, x: 0.3, y: -0.3, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInJump, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Left: [0, 0.8], $Top: [0, 0.8] }, $Round: { $Left: 0.8, $Top: 2.5} };
            _CaptionTransitions["FLUTTER|L"] = { $Duration: 600, x: 0.2, y: -0.1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInWave }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };
            _CaptionTransitions["TORTUOUS|VB"] = { $Duration: 1200, y: -0.2, $Zoom: 1, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutWave, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $During: { $Top: [0, 0.7] }, $Round: { $Top: 1.3} };
            _CaptionTransitions["FADE"] = { $Duration: 600, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["ZMF|10"] = { $Duration: 600, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 };
            _CaptionTransitions["RTT|10"] = { $Duration: 600, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
            _CaptionTransitions["RTTL|BR"] = { $Duration: 600, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };

            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
                $AutoPlaySteps: 1,                                  //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), the default value is 1
                $AutoPlayInterval: 4000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
                $PauseOnHover: 1,                               //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

                $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
                $SlideDuration: 500,                                //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
                $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
                //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
                //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
                $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
                $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
                $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
                $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
                $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
                $DragOrientation: 3,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

                $SlideshowOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable slideshow or not
                    $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,                 //[Required] Class to create instance of slideshow
                    $Transitions: _SlideshowTransitions,            //[Required] An array of slideshow transitions to play slideshow
                    $TransitionsOrder: 1,                           //[Optional] The way to choose transition to play slide, 1 Sequence, 0 Random
                    $ShowLink: true                                    //[Optional] Whether to bring slide link on top of the slider when slideshow is running, default value is false
                },

                $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                    $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                    $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                    $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                    $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                },

                $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                                //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                    $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                       //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $ActionMode: 3,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                    $Lanes: 2,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                    $SpacingX: 10,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                    $SpacingY: 10                                    //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                },

                $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,              //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 1                                //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                },

                $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                    $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,              //[Required] Class to create thumbnail navigator instance
                    $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                    $ActionMode: 0,                                 //[Optional] 0 None, 1 act by click, 2 act by mouse hover, 3 both, default value is 1
                    $DisableDrag: true,                             //[Optional] Disable drag or not, default value is false
                    $Orientation: 2                                 //[Optional] Orientation to arrange thumbnails, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, default value is 1
                }
            };

            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);
            //responsive code begin
            //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
            function ScaleSlider() {
                var parentWidth = jssor_slider1.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
                if (parentWidth)
                    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth,600));
                else
                    window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
            ScaleSlider();

            $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
            $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
            //responsive code end
        });
    </script>

 <!--end script jassor slider >
 <!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
    <!-- You can move inline styles to css file or css block. -->


    <div id="slider1_container"  style="position:relative;  width:600px;
        height: 300px;">

        <!-- Loading Screen -->
        <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">

            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity:0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #000; top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(imgages/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
                top: 0px; left: 0px;width: 100%;height:100%;">
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Slides Container -->
        <div u="slides" class="jasso-sl" style="cursor: move;  position:absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width:1365px ; height: 450px;
            overflow: hidden;">
            <div>
                <img u=image src="images/landscape/01.jpg" />
                <div u="thumb">Do you Need To be The First One in your field ?</div>
                <div u="caption" t="L" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 20px; line-height:80px;">Your Academy</div>
                <div u="caption" t="CLIP|LR" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 100px; width: 400px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Only with heaven you can be the Best</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u=image src="images/landscape/02.jpg" />
                <div u="thumb">We have more one offer to satisfy you</div>
                <div u="caption" t="MCLIP|L" style="position: absolute; top: 105px; left: 100px; width: 400px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;"> pay less .Learn more  </div>
                <div u="caption" t="LISTH|L" style="position: absolute; top: 165px; left: 100px; width: 400px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Achieve your goals  </div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u=image src="images/landscape/03.jpg" />
                <div u="thumb">Never Stop withs our team ,all news with us</div>
                <div u="caption" t="WAVE|L" t2="T" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 450px; width: 100px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Challange</div>
                <div u="caption" t="WAVE|L" t2="T" d="-1150" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 250px; width: 100px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Future</div>
                <div u="caption" t="WAVE|L" t2="T" d="-1150" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 50px; width: 100px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Dreams</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u=image src="images/landscape/04.jpg" />
                <div u="thumb">Do you like to have all this course?</div>
                <div u="caption" t="JUMPDN|R" t2="B" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 50px; width: 100px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Web Courses</div>
                <div u="caption" t="JUMPDN|R" t2="B" d="-850" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 250px; width: 100px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Programming Courses</div>
                <div u="caption" t="JUMPDN|R" t2="B" d="-850" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 450px; width: 100px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Academic Courses</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u=image src="images/landscape/01.jpg" />
                <div u="thumb">Do you need to be one from us?</div>
                <div u="caption" t="DDG|TR" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 100px; width: 150px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Visit|Us</div>
                <div u="caption" t="DODGEDANCE|L" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 300px; width: 250px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Never|Stop</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u=image src="images/landscape/02.jpg" />
                <div u="thumb">Do you notice the slideshow plays outside?</div>
                <div u="caption" t="FLUTTER|L" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 100px; width: 150px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">FLUTTER|L</div>
                <div u="caption" t="TORTUOUS|VB" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 300px; width: 250px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">TORTUOUS|VB</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u=image src="images/landscape/03.jpg" />
                <div u="thumb">Do you know there are Our prices<a href="../development/tool-slideshow-transition-viewer.html"></a>?</div>
                <div u="caption" t="FADE" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 100px; width: 150px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">The Leaset </div>
                <div u="caption" t="ZMF|10" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 300px; width: 250px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">price|For You</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <img u=image src="images/landscape/04.jpg" />
                <div u="thumb">Do you know there are All Courses<a href="../development/tool-caption-transition-viewer.html"> </a>?</div>
                <div u="caption" t="RTT|10" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 100px; width: 150px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Academic|20 course</div>
                <div u="caption" t="RTTL|BR" style="position: absolute; top: 135px; left: 300px; width: 250px; height: 30px; color: #ffffff; font-size: 26px; line-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Non Academic|40 course</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin Begin -->
        <div u="thumbnavigator" class="slider1-T" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; height:60px; width:600px;">
            <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=40); opacity:0.4; position: absolute; display: block;
                background-color: #ffffff; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
            <div u="slides">
                <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 600px; HEIGHT: 60px; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0;">
                    <div u="thumbnailtemplate" style="font-family: verdana; font-weight: normal; POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 100%; TOP: 0; LEFT: 0; color:#000; line-height: 60px; font-size:20px; padding-left:10px;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
        </div>
        <!-- ThumbnailNavigator Skin End -->

        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <!-- jssor slider bullet navigator skin 01 -->
        <style>
            /*
            .jssorb01 div           (normal)
            .jssorb01 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
            .jssorb01 .av           (active)
            .jssorb01 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
            .jssorb01 .dn           (mousedown)
            */
            .jssorb01 div, .jssorb01 div:hover, .jssorb01 .av
            {
                filter: alpha(opacity=70);
                opacity: .7;
                overflow:hidden;
                cursor: pointer;
                border: #000 1px solid;
            }
            .jssorb01 div { background-color: gray; }

            .jssorb01 .dn, .jssorb01 .dn:hover { background-color: #555555; }
        </style>
        <!-- bullet navigator container -->
        <div u="navigator" class="jssorb01" style="position: absolute; bottom: 16px; right: 10px;">
            <!-- bullet navigator item prototype -->
            <div u="prototype" style="POSITION: absolute; WIDTH: 12px; HEIGHT: 12px;"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bullet Navigator Skin End -->

        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
        <style>
            /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
            /*
            .jssora05l              (normal)
            .jssora05r              (normal)
            .jssora05l:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora05r:hover        (normal mouseover)
            .jssora05ldn            (mousedown)
            .jssora05rdn            (mousedown)
            */
            .jssora05l, .jssora05r, .jssora05ldn, .jssora05rdn
            {
                position: absolute;
                cursor: pointer;
                display: block;
                background: url(imgages/a17.png) no-repeat;
                overflow:hidden;
            }
            .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
            .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
            .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
            .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
            .jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
            .jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }
        </style>
        <!-- Arrow Left -->
        <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 123px; left: 8px;">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Right -->
        <span u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; top: 123px; right: 8px">
        </span>
        <!-- Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
        <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">jQuery Slider</a>
        <!-- Trigger -->
    </div>
    <!-- Jssor Slider End -->
<!--end caursol-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indicates you scale the slider to width of maximum 600px.

Please replace

```
jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth,600));
```

with

```
jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(parentWidth);
```

Btw, you'd set original size of your slider container to 1365x450.

```
<div id="slider1_container"  style="position:relative; width: 1365px;
        height: 450px;">
```